# Understanding the dependence of conditional probability on filtrations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Given a sequence of iid random variables $\{X_n\}$ (not necessarily discrete), and defining the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}_{\mathcal{F}_n}(A)(\omega)$ where the filtration is the natural one and $A$ is an event in the probability space. I am interested in understanding the connection between the conditional probability and $\omega$. Usually one provides the following example, tipically using the discrete case (or more in general a partitioning): for example if $\omega\in\{X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n\}$, $\mathbb{P}_{\mathcal{F}_n}(A)(\omega)=\mathbb{P}(A|X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)$, because the events $\{X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n\}$ are a partitioning generating $\mathcal{F}_n$. My question is essentially if more generally (that is not just in the case of a partitioning) this relationship extends to some measurable events $H\in\mathcal{F}_n$: when do we have that $\mathbb{P}_{\mathcal{F}_n}(A)(\omega)=\mathbb{P}(A|H)$ for all $\omega\in H$? Thanks for any insight provided.
EDIT: As an example, from a paper I read, the following relationship, reminiscent of the above, holds: if $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ are uniform on $(0,1)$, $\mathbb{P}_{\mathcal{F}_n}(X_n=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_N\})=1_{\{X_n=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\}}X_n^{N-n}$. What properties have been used to derive it?

Comment: This certainly can't be true: Take $H = \Omega$ as an example.  If this were true, it would imply $\mathbb{P}_{\mathcal F_n}(A)(\omega) = \mathbb{P}(A|\Omega)=\mathbb{P}(A)$ for all $\omega$.

Comment: You are right, I was implicitly assuming $H$ nontrivial, and I do not believe myself that, even with this assumption, measurability alone is sufficient. I am trying to see what conditions $H$ has to satisfy to yield the result for $\omega\in H$.

Comment: This is true if $H$ is an atom of $\mathcal F_n$, but not in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally true if $H$ is an atom of $\mathcal F_n$, i.e. if $G \in \mathcal F_n$ and $G$ is a strict subset of $H$ implies $\mathbb{P}(G)=0$.  Otherwise, if $H = H_1 \cup H_2$, it would imply $\mathbb{P}(A|H)=\mathbb{P}(A|H_1)=\mathbb{P}(A|H_2)$.  The reason this isn't a problem for atoms is because conditional probabilities aren't defined for events with probability zero.

For the specific example you asked about, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}_{\mathcal F_n}(X_n = \max(X_1,...,X_N)) &= \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal F_n}[1_{X_n = \max(X_1,...,X_N)}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal F_n}[1_{X_n = \max(X_1,...,X_n)} 1_{X_{n+1}\le X_n} \cdots 1_{X_N \le X_n}] \\
&= 1_{X_n = \max(X_1,...,X_n)}\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal F_n}[1_{X_{n+1}\le X_n}] \cdots \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal F_n}[ 1_{X_N \le X_n}] \\
&= 1_{X_n = \max(X_1,...,X_n)} X_n \cdots X_n \\
&= 1_{X_n = \max(X_1,...,X_n)} X_n^{N-n},
\end{align}
where the third equality follows from independence and taking out what is known, and the fourth from the fact that $X_{n+1},...,X_N \sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: You surely meant N-n in the final step. Thank you so much for helping me understand, now it all makes sense. I am very grateful.

Comment: @GGG Yes, sorry about that!  I fixed it - thanks!